# pySNMP Agent with custom mib loaded from file

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp, mib

I have for a couple of days been looking for a solution to a problem.

I'm supposed to implement an SNMP agent that is SNMP v2c compliant, but in my quest to get there I have gotten stuck on writing an agent that can serve a manager with a predefined MIB file.

Is there any way for me to load a mib file into my python program and have it serve the OID in the mib. Of course, I know that I need to implement some mechanism to update the values of the OID's as the values in the real world change.

I have been looking at examples and reading the documentation at http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/ but I don't seem to be able to find a good solution, and some of the examples on the git repository seem to be broken. Also, all the similar questions I have found on stack overflow seem to be outdated as well.

Hope someone can point me to an example that can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is that MIB file does **not** contain any values you could serve to your manager. MIB is just a schema, so to speak.

Therefore what you may need to do is to "instantiate" a MIB e.g. do two things:

1. Create a bunch of OIDs out of those described in MIB
2. Attach some static values or callbacks to [pull the actual values](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html#implementing-scalar-mib-objects) to the manager

Let's see what is broken in the pysnmp repo? I'm eager to fix that. ;-)

Comment: Is there a good example of this on the website? And also if I have a custom datatype `NonNegativeInteger ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION` or even just `DisplayString` how do I define these?

Comment: Keep in mind that TEXTUAL-CONVENTION is designed mostly for pretty rendering of the value on the receiving side (e.g. SNMP manager). Consider MAC address as an example. On the SNMP level it is defined as a sequence of octets, while SNMP manager would use MIB definition to format it into conventional human-friendly form (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx). Your agent would better operate on "raw" values (belonging to base SNMP types such as string or integer) rather than on prettily formatted. So you can completely ignore TEXTUAL-CONVENTION. ;-)